# How do I parse subarrays with SOAP::Lite?

Tags: xml, perl, soap

I am writing a perl script to call a third party's web service and parse the response XML so that the data can be written into a database.  I've been advised to use SOAP::Lite (currently using 1.14 within Strawberry Perl 5.22.0.1 for Windows 64-bit).

The response may look something like this:

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <getEventsResponse>
      <GetEventsResponse>
        <events>
          <Event>
            <EventAttr1>valueofattr1</EventAttr1>
            <EventAttr2>valueofattr2</EventAttr2>
            <EventAttr3>valueofattr3</EventAttr3>
          </Event>
          <Event>
            <EventAttr1>valueofattr1</EventAttr1>
            <EventAttr2>valueofattr2</EventAttr2>
            <EventAttr3>valueofattr3</EventAttr3>
          </Event>
          <Event>
            <EventAttr1>valueofattr1</EventAttr1>
            <EventAttr2>valueofattr2</EventAttr2>
            <EventAttr3>valueofattr3</EventAttr3>
          </Event>
          <Event>
            <EventAttr1>valueofattr1</EventAttr1>
            <EventAttr2>valueofattr2</EventAttr2>
            <EventAttr3>valueofattr3</EventAttr3>
          </Event>
          .
          .
          .
       </events>
      </GetEventsResponse>
    </getEventsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Where `valueofattr1` could be a unique identifier for that Event object and the number of Events is variable.  Each Event has the same attrs.

To retrieve and evaluate the Events, I'm using the following package and code:

```
package EventServices;
use SOAP::Lite;
sub new {
    my ($class)            = shift;
    my ($url)              = shift;
    my ($soapuser)         = shift;
    my ($soappasswordhash) = shift;
    my $self = {
        "url"              => $url,
        "soapuser"         => $soapuser,
        "soappasswordhash" => $soappasswordhash,
        "client"           => undef
};
bless $self, 'EventServices';
return $self;
}
sub connect {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{client} =
        SOAP::Lite->uri('http://3rdparty.co.uk')
        ->proxy( $self->{url} . '/hosted/services/EventServicesWS' );

    $self->{client}->autotype(0); 
    # This stops SOAP::DATA automatically adding type definitions within every
    # XML element, which is often wrong and fails the XSD validation.
}   
sub getBatch {
my $self            = shift;
my $startDate       = shift;
my $endDate         = shift;

my $result =
$self->{client}->getEvents(
    SOAP::Data->prefix('ns2')->uri('http://3rdparty.co.uk')->name("userContext" =>
                            \SOAP::Data->value(
                            SOAP::Data->prefix('ns1')
                            .
                            .
                            .
              )
        )
    );
    return $result;
}
1;
```

---

```
my $fs = new EventServices( "https://3rdparty.co.uk", "<username>", "<hashedpassed>" );
$fs->connect();
$result = $fs->getBatch($startDate, $endDate);
for my $event ( $result->valueof('//getEventsResponse/GetEventsResponse/events/Event'))
{
  my $e_eventAttr1 = $event->{e_eventAttr1};
  my $e_eventAttr2 = $event->{e_eventAttr2};
  my $e_eventAttr3 = $event->{e_eventAttr3};
  .
  .
  .
}
```

This all works fine and the code loops through each Event happily.  As ever I can well believe there's more than one way to have achieved this, but this is simple enough all to follow.

Having looped through an array of Events, I now need to explore how to loop through a sub-array within each Event.  The XML now looks something like this:

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <getEventsResponse>
      <GetEventsResponse>
        <events>
          <Event>
            <EventAttr1>valueofattr1</EventAttr1>
            <EventAttr2>valueofattr2</EventAttr2>
            <EventMessages>
              <EventMessageDetail>
                <MessageType>type1</MessageType>
                <MessageText>textOfTheMessageForType1</MessageText>
              <\EventMessageDetail>
              <EventMessageDetail>
                <MessageType>type2</MessageType>
                <MessageText>textOfTheMessageForType2</MessageText>
              <\EventMessageDetail>
              <EventMessageDetail>
                <MessageType>type3</MessageType>
                <MessageText>textOfTheMessageForType3</MessageText>
              <\EventMessageDetail>
              .
              .
              .
            </EventMessages>
            <EventAttr3>valueofattr3</EventAttr3>
          </Event>
          <Event>
            <EventAttr1>valueofattr1</EventAttr1>
            <EventAttr2>valueofattr2</EventAttr2>
            <EventMessages>
              <EventMessageDetail>
                <MessageType>type1</MessageType>
                <MessageText>textOfTheMessageForType1</MessageText>
              <\EventMessageDetail>
              <EventMessageDetail>
                <MessageType>type2</MessageType>
                <MessageText>textOfTheMessageForType2</MessageText>
              <\EventMessageDetail>
              <EventMessageDetail>
                <MessageType>type3</MessageType>
                <MessageText>textOfTheMessageForType3</MessageText>
              <\EventMessageDetail>
              .
              .
              .
            </EventMessages>
            <EventAttr3>valueofattr3</EventAttr3>
          </Event>
          <Event>
            <EventAttr1>valueofattr1</EventAttr1>
            <EventAttr2>valueofattr2</EventAttr2>
            <EventMessages>
              <EventMessageDetail>
                <MessageType>type1</MessageType>
                <MessageText>textOfTheMessageForType1</MessageText>
              <\EventMessageDetail>
              <EventMessageDetail>
                <MessageType>type2</MessageType>
                <MessageText>textOfTheMessageForType2</MessageText>
              <\EventMessageDetail>
              <EventMessageDetail>
                <MessageType>type3</MessageType>
                <MessageText>textOfTheMessageForType3</MessageText>
              <\EventMessageDetail>
              .
              .
              .
            </EventMessages>
            <EventAttr3>valueofattr3</EventAttr3>
          </Event>
          <Event>
            <EventAttr1>valueofattr1</EventAttr1>
            <EventAttr2>valueofattr2</EventAttr2>
            <EventMessages>
              <EventMessageDetail>
                <MessageType>type1</MessageType>
                <MessageText>textOfTheMessageForType1</MessageText>
              <\EventMessageDetail>
              <EventMessageDetail>
                <MessageType>type2</MessageType>
                <MessageText>textOfTheMessageForType2</MessageText>
              <\EventMessageDetail>
              <EventMessageDetail>
                <MessageType>type3</MessageType>
                <MessageText>textOfTheMessageForType3</MessageText>
              <\EventMessageDetail>
              .
              .
              .
            </EventMessages>
            <EventAttr3>valueofattr3</EventAttr3>
          </Event>
          .
          .
          .
        </events>
      </GetEventsResponse>
    </getEventsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I should strictly not assume Events have the same number of EventMessages, if
any.

I would like to have a `for` loop within the outer `for` loop of Events, but I found that if I tried `$result->valueof('//getEventsResponse/GetEventsResponse/events/Event/EventMessages/EventMessageDetail')` then the inner `for` loop works through all EventMessageDetails, for all Events, and not just the EventMessageDetails for the Event captured by the outer for loop.

I took a stab at using [n] to reference the current Event from the outer `for` loop within a `$result->match( )`, but could not make heads nor tails of how it should work.

Can anyone tell me how I could approach this problem?

---

**ONE SOLUTION:**

Following a tip to look at DATA::Dumper I finally found adding the following code within the main `for` loop worked a treat.

```
use Data::Dumper
my $a = Dumper($Event->{'EventMessages'}->{'EventMessageDetail'});
eval $a;
for my $MessageDetail (@{$VAR1}) {
  print "MessageType: $MessageDetail->{MessageType}; \n";
  print "MessageText = $MessageDetail->{MessageText}; \n";
}
```

---

**ANSWER:**

Here is a cleaner and faster to execute coding method, that does not require the Data::Dumper module at all:

```
for my $MessageDetail ( @{ $Event->{'EventMessages'}->{'EventMessageDetail'} } ) { 
  print "MessageType: $MessageDetail->{MessageType}; \n";
  print "MessageText = $MessageDetail->{MessageText}; \n";
}
```

Comment: use Data::Printer (or Data::Dumper) to output `$event` inside the loop.

Comment: `my $a = Dumper($event->{ ‘EventMessages’}->{'EventMessageDetails'}->[$i]);` within a `for` loop incrementing `$I` returns the string `$VAR1 = […];` with `{‘MessageType => ‘<value>’, ‘MessageText=>’value’}` for that EventMessageDetails element. `eval $a;` allows me use `${$VAR1}{"MessageType"}` and `${$VAR1}{"MessageText"}`. Incrementing `$i` too far returns `$VAR1 = undef;` so I’d like a more elegant way to loop through the elements of Dumper output, can’t get `for my $key (keys %a) {print "$key, $a{$key}\n";}` to work with `my $a = Dumper($event->{ ‘EventMessages’}->{'EventMessageDetails'}`.

Comment: Can you add that to the question in a readable fashion please? It's a bit too messy in a comment. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: I finally got `eval $a; for my $EventMessage (@{$VAR1}) {print “MessageType=$EventMessage->{MessageType}\n”;}` to work.

Comment: Don't name stuff `$a`. That's a reserved variable in `sort` blocks. See perlvar.

Comment: Understood.  This is only an example, not actual code :)

Comment: What did you do? Why the `eval`? You've basically serialized and deserialized the data structure. You can just not have the `Dumper(...)` call and just use that thing directly. `for my $MessageDetail ( @{ $Event->{'EventMessages'}->{'EventMessageDetail'} } ) { ... }`

Comment: Yes, that does work too. Though from the perspective of a newbie like me we wouldn't appreciate why or understand how it worked. I'll update the suffix to the original question and then answer it.  Thanks.  I hope others reading this get all the supporting information they need.

Answer (score 0):

So the simple answer is `for my $MessageDetail ( @{ $Event->{'EventMessages'}->{'EventMessageDetail'} } ) {...}`.

Thank you [simbabque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331451/simbabque).